# Normalizing all numeric columns in my dataset and compare before and after

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, normalization, static-analysis

I want to normalize all the numeric values in my dataset.

I have taken my whole dataset into a pandas dataframe.

My code to do this so far:

```
for column in numeric:     #numeric=df._get_numeric_data()

        x_array=np.array(df[column])
        normalized_X=preprocessing.normalize([x_array])
```

But how do i verify this is correct though?
I tried plotting a histogram for one of the columns before normalizing and after adding this piece of code before and after my for loop:

```
x=df['Below.Primary']      #Below.Primary is one of my column names
plt.hist(x, bins=45)
```

[image: Before the for loop]
[image: After the for loop]

The blue histogram was before the for loop and the orange, after. 
My total code looked like this:

```
ln[21]  plt.hist(df['Below.Primary'], bins=45)

ln[22]  for column in numeric:
             x_array=np.array(df[column])
             normalized_X=preprocessing.normalize([x_array])

        x=df['Below.Primary']
        plt.hist(x, bins=45)
```

I don't see any reduction in scale. What have i done wrong? If not correct, can someone point out the correct way to do what i wanted to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple general things first.

- If numeric is a list of column names (looks like this is the case), the for loop is not necessary.
- A Pandas series using an `ndarray` under the hood so you can just request the `ndarray` with `Series.values` instead of calling `np.array()`. [See this page on the Pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html#pandas.Series.array).
- I am assuming you are using [preprocessing from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing).

I recommend using sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer for this.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer

### Without the for loop (recommended)
# this version returns array

normalizer = Normalizer()
normalized_values = normalizer.fit_transform(df[numeric])

# normalized_values is a 2D array which is useful
# for many applications
# to convert back to DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame(normalized_values, columns = numeric)


### with the for-loop (not recommended)

for column in numeric:
    x_array = df[column].values.reshape(-1,1)
    df[column] = normalizer.fit_transform(x_array)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use this:

```
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
df[col] = scaler.fit_transform(df[col])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set normalized_X to the respective column while iterating.

```
for column in numeric:
         x_array=np.array(df[column])
         normalized_X=preprocessing.normalize([x_array])
         df[column]= normalized_X #Setting normalized value in the column

    x=df['Below.Primary']
    plt.hist(x, bins=45)
```